# Inline JavaScript code not working

Tags: javascript, image

I want to change image while `mouseover` and `mouseout`

MY Code :

```
<img src="convert.php?file=image.gif" title="Preview image"
   width="100" height="100" rel="image.gif"
   onmouseover="this.src=this.rel"
   onmouseout="this.src='convert.php?file='+this.rel" />
```

`this.rel` getting `undefined`. Please check and help me. :(

Comment: `this.src=this.rel`? never seen it before.

Comment: What are you expecting this.rel to be?  I don't see any reason for it to have a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img src="convert.php?file=image.gif" title="Preview image"
   width="100" height="100" rel="image.gif"
   onmouseover="this.src=this.getAttribute('rel')"
   onmouseout="this.src='convert.php?file='+this.getAttribute('rel')" />
```

Comment: ur welcome.you can accept the answer if my answer helped you.